# Error : Invalid Reference Format in Dockerfile ubuntu 14.04, cuda 8.0, cudnn 6.0

Tags: docker, cudnn

I am trying to build an image from the Dockerfile of specifications ubuntu 14.04, cuda 8.0, cudnn 6.0 (devel) from [here](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/cuda/blob/ubuntu14.04/8.0/devel/cudnn6/Dockerfile).

I saved  the dockerfile on my local system
When I use docker build PATH command where

> PATH = /home/anil/Desktop/container

I get the following error :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/7 : ARG IMAGE_NAME
Step 2/7 : FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}:8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04
invalid reference format
```

I am using Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an argument called `IMAGE_NAME` during the build like this:

```
docker build --build-arg IMAGE_NAME=nvidia/cuda .
```

The output:

```
Step 1/7 : ARG IMAGE_NAME
Step 2/7 : FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}:8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04
8.0-devel-ubuntu14.04: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
```